# Switching Atlassian Confluence under Caddy instead of NGINX

Tags: nginx, confluence, caddy, caddyfile

So I recently started getting issues with NGINX crashing for unknown reasons.

After passing to much time on trying to fix it I decided to move to Caddy instead.

My caddy configuration works for navigating the website, but it breaks the `/synchrony` access, used when editing the pages. The *pure* websocket part works, I tested using http://websocket.org/echo.html, but Confluence also retrieves some scripts through that path.

I used the following as reference for troobleshooting: https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf60/troubleshooting-collaborative-editing-852732552.html

**My working NGINX configuration**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name [REDACTED];

    ssl_certificate [REDACTED];
    ssl_certificate_key [REDACTED];

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    }
    location /synchrony {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8091/synchrony;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
}
```

**My suggested equivalent non-working Caddy configuration**

```
https://[REDACTED] {
  log access.log
  errors error.log
  gzip
  tls "C:\caddy\[REDACTED].cer" "C:\caddy\[REDACTED].key"

  proxy /synchrony http://localhost:8091/synchrony {
    websocket
  }

  proxy / http://localhost:8090 {
    except /synchrony
    transparent
  }
}
```

The above is based on the following documentation: https://caddyserver.com/docs/proxy
It uses the `transparent` & `websocket` presets.

**The main error that seems to be blocking the edit page**
[image: Chrome Developer Tools Network screenshot of failing request]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to use the `without` parameter.

> `without` is a URL prefix to trim before proxying the request upstream. A request to `/api/foo` `without /api`, for example, will result in a proxy request to `/foo`.

You may try this:

```
https://[REDACTED] {
  log access.log
  errors error.log
  gzip
  tls "C:\caddy\[REDACTED].cer" "C:\caddy\[REDACTED].key"

  proxy /synchrony http://localhost:8091/synchrony {
    websocket
    without /synchrony
  }

  proxy / http://localhost:8090 {
    except /synchrony
    transparent      
  }
}
```